# how to catch tab button in shell line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I want create a script with default arguments, of manner how some commands display default arguments  pressing tab button in linux

In first instance I want to catch the tab button with the command trap, but it is not a correct way since the tab button  shall  trapped by the shell before to execute the script and no after

the questions are, 
How catch the tab button in the shell before execute the program and display the default arguments than can get the script or program?

Have a demon, bind key,or config file that allow to pass default arguments to shell line?

**Note:**

I regularly use bash in gnome-terminal  , I think what the auto-complete of arguments have to see with type of terminal, i'm not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the Bash completion feature. As a super simple example suppose your script is called `my_script` and accepts the arguments `foo` and `bar`, you may write something like this in a file:

```
_complete_script_options() {
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "foo bar" -- ${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}) 
}
complete -F _complete_script_options my_script
```

and then load the file in you bash session using `source file_with_completion`.

For further informations you may want to see http://www.debian-administration.org/article/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1 and the Bash manual page.